# Custom response body for validate-jwt in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I am validating JWT token from Azure API Manager. I am looking for options to change the response body when the validation fails. As per documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies.

```
<validate-jwt
    header-name="name of http header containing the token (use query-parameter-name attribute if the token is passed in the URL)"
    failed-validation-httpcode="401"
    failed-validation-error-message="Invalid Token"
    token-value="expression returning JWT token as a string"
    require-expiration-time="true|false"
    require-scheme="scheme"
    require-signed-tokens="true|false"
    clock-skew="allowed clock skew in seconds"
    output-token-variable-name="name of a variable to receive a JWT object representing successfully validated token">
```

If i set

```
  failed-validation-httpcode="401" and  failed-validation-error-message="Invalid Token"
```

the response when the validation fails would be

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Token"
}
```

Now i need to change the "statusCode" in the body to "status" response to

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Token"
}
```

Is it possible in Azure API Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to fix this with the following transformation policy.

```
 <on-error>
     <choose>
         <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 401)">
            <find-and-replace from="statusCode" to="status" />
         </when>
    </choose> 
</on-error>
```

Comment: This is working as expected. But, I wanted to set header `WWW-Authenticate : Bearer realm="my_sample_realm"`. Here the header key turning to lower case in the response instead of preserving case as `WWW-Authenticate`. Is there any way to preserve the case?

Comment: Can you please add your inbound configuration?

Comment: <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized." require-scheme="Bearer">
 <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_org_id/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
      <audiences>
         <audience>my_audience</audience>
     </audiences>
     <issuers>
        <issuer>my_issuer</issuer>
     </issuers>
     <required-claims>
     <claim name="roles" match="any">
        <value>clients.manage</value>
    </claim>
  </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>

Comment: This is my JWT validation inside `<inbound>` tag.

Comment: Can you please post a question with details/find-replace method you have used..? I am not able to relate sorry

Comment: Asked a new question s per your suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288455/azure-apim-response-headers-turning-to-lower-case @Justin Mathew